# How do I iterate a list of values into a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, iteration

I am new to Python so please excuse my lack of understanding.

I am able to download data for `aapl` using BeatifulSoup4, assign the data to specific variables and create a dictionary with the variables. What I would like to do though is to iterate the `stock` list through the website link and run the same code multiple times for different companies in the list and end up with a dictionary for each company.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request


stocks = ['aapl', 'nvda', 'amgn']

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/aapl/balance-sheet')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

#Cash & Cash Equivalents
cash_and_equivalents2017 = soup.find_all('td')[33].string
cash_and_equivalents2017 = int(cash_and_equivalents2017.replace(',',''))
cash_and_equivalents2016 = soup.find_all('td')[34].string
cash_and_equivalents2016 = int(cash_and_equivalents2016.replace(',',''))

#Receivables
receivables2017 = soup.find_all('td')[40].string
receivables2017 = int(receivables2017.replace(',',''))
receivables2016 = soup.find_all('td')[41].string
receivables2016 = int(receivables2016.replace(',',''))


aapl = {'Cash & Cash Equivalents':
            {'2017': cash_and_equivalents2017,
             '2016': cash_and_equivalents2016},
        'Receivables':
            {'2017': receivables2017,
             '2016': receivables2016}
        }
print(aapl)
```

Which outputs the following for `aapl`:

```
{'Cash & Cash Equivalents': {'2017': 74181, '2016': 67155}, 'Receivables': {'2017': 29299, '2016': 30343}}
```

The above is the original code and I would like to substitute `aapl` in `sauce` for the other string values in `stocks` to eventually get multiple dictionaries as shown below so that I am able to automatically download data for various companies into 3 different dictionaries by just inputting them in the `stock` list.

```
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/[stocks]/balance-sheet')

[stocks] = {'Cash & Cash Equivalents':
                {'2017': cash_and_equivalents2017,
                 '2016': cash_and_equivalents2016},
            'Receivables':
                {'2017': receivables2017,
                 '2016': receivables2016}
```

And the output should be 3 dictionaries with the names `aapl`, `nvda`, `amgn`.

```
aapl = {'Cash & Cash Equivalents':
            {'2017': cash_and_equivalents2017,
             '2016': cash_and_equivalents2016},
        'Receivables':
            {'2017': receivables2017,
             '2016': receivables2016}

nvda = {'Cash & Cash Equivalents':
            {'2017': cash_and_equivalents2017,
             '2016': cash_and_equivalents2016},
        'Receivables':
            {'2017': receivables2017,
             '2016': receivables2016}

amgn = {'Cash & Cash Equivalents':
            {'2017': cash_and_equivalents2017,
             '2016': cash_and_equivalents2016},
        'Receivables':
            {'2017': receivables2017,
             '2016': receivables2016}
```

Thank you for time and help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: You will have to loop over using each value in stocks to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I correctly understood your question.

Do you want to make one request and processing for each entry in `stocks = ['aapl', 'nvda', 'amgn']`?

If so, in Python you can iterate over a list or dict with a for loop like so:

```
for stock in stocks:
    # Do your processing here
```

What you could do in your case is the following:

Use a dict instead of a list and store your processed datas in it.

```
stocks = {'aapl': {}, 'nvda': {}, 'amgn': {}}
for stock in stocks:

    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(
        f'https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/{stock}/balance-sheet')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

    # Cash & Cash Equivalents
    cash_and_equivalents2017 = soup.find_all('td')[33].string
    cash_and_equivalents2017 = int(cash_and_equivalents2017.replace(',', ''))
    cash_and_equivalents2016 = soup.find_all('td')[34].string
    cash_and_equivalents2016 = int(cash_and_equivalents2016.replace(',', ''))

    # Receivables
    receivables2017 = soup.find_all('td')[40].string
    receivables2017 = int(receivables2017.replace(',', ''))
    receivables2016 = soup.find_all('td')[41].string
    receivables2016 = int(receivables2016.replace(',', ''))

    stocks[stock] = {'Cash & Cash Equivalents':
                     {'2017': cash_and_equivalents2017,
                      '2016': cash_and_equivalents2016},
                     'Receivables':
                     {'2017': receivables2017,
                         '2016': receivables2016}
                     }

print(stocks)
```

As for the url string, I used the [litteral string interpolation method](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Will output the following:

```
{
    'aapl': 
    {
        'Cash & Cash Equivalents': 
        {
            '2017': 'some value', 
            '2016': 'some value'
        }, 
        'Receivables': 
        {
            '2017': 'some value', 
            '2016': 'some value'
            }
    }, 
    'nvda': 
    {
        'Cash & Cash Equivalents': 
        {
            '2017': 'some value', 
            '2016': 'some value'
        }, 
        'Receivables':
        {
            '2017': 'some value', 
            '2016': 'some value'
        }
    }, 
    'amgn': 
    {
        'Cash & Cash Equivalents': 
        {
            '2017': 'some value', 
            '2016': 'some value'
        }, 
        'Receivables': 
        {
            '2017': 'some value', 
            '2016': 'some value'
        }
    }
}
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

append each response into one list like this and upack the values from dictioanry:

```
aapl, nvda, amgn = [{'Cash & Cash Equivalents': {'2017': 74181, '2016': 67155}, 'Receivables': {'2017': 29299, '2016': 30343}},{'Cash & Cash Equivalents': {'2017': 74181, '2016': 67155}, 'Receivables': {'2017': 29299, '2016': 30343}},{'Cash & Cash Equivalents': {'2017': 74181, '2016': 67155}, 'Receivables': {'2017': 29299, '2016': 30343}}]
```